# Can I host multiple nodejs custom domains on Heroku Hobby plan?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have tried Heroku's free plan and I can host multiple NodeJS apps there. But as the dyno sleeps after 30 mins of activity in this plan, I was thinking of using Hobby plan. Just wanted to know if we can host multiple custom domains on Hobby plan? Can all custom domains work 24/7 for the same cost which is $7/month ?

Comment: That is the question to the [Heroku support](https://www.heroku.com/support) team rather than to StackOverflow because don't have much to do with programming.

Comment: Please read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#rules-on-adding-domains. This explicitly sais: `A single application can have any number of domains assigned to it.` and the documentation gives enough guidelines how imho :)

Comment: @KristoMägi Thanks for your help. But actually I wanted to ask whether we can host multiple apps (each having its own custom domain).

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj No, you can not run multiple processes in one free or hobby dyno as said in documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#default-scaling-limits): `The free and hobby dyno types only support a maximum of one dyno running per process type.`

Comment: Thanks @KristoMägi, but is one dyno capable of only one app? In my free account, I have already tried creating 2 separate apps (one uses a custom domain and one uses heroku app domain) and these work fine. Just wanted to confirm if same thing can be done with Hobby plan and then can both apps run 24/7 for whole month? On free plan both apps work, but as these are experimental so these run for quite small spans of time over a month. So not sure how this turns out with hobby plan. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Hobby plan doesn't change how you deploy. If it worked in Free then same works on Hobby and the 24/7 works remains true (meaning works).